# Multiple Endpoints in Cassandra cluster Connection

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to give multiple Cassandra endpoints from the config file to my Java application.

Ex: 
cassandra host: "host1, host2"

I tried `addContactPoints(host)`, but it did not work. If one of the Cassandra node goes down, I don't want my application to go down.

```java
cluster = Cluster.builder()
  .withClusterName(cassandraConfig.getClusterName())
  .addContactPoints(cassandraConfig.getHostName())
  .withSocketOptions(new SocketOptions().setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000).setReadTimeoutMillis(30000))
  .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions).build();
```

Comment: Can you please share the exception are you are observing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java driver is resilient to one of the contact points provided not being available. Contact points are used for establishing an initial connection [*].  As long as the driver is able to communicate with one contact point, it should be able to query the `system.peers` and `system.local` table to discover the rest of the nodes in the cluster.

* They are also added to a list of initial hosts in the cluster, but typically the contact points provided map to a node in the system.peers table.

Comment: if the IP what we are giving that is down means, we cannot connect to the cluster right.

Comment: Correct, typically you will want to provide IPs for multiple nodes in your local data center to be resilient to a node going down affecting the ability to initialize a driver with a Cluster.  As long as the driver is able to communicate with one contact point, that should be ok.